# Confused in my Linear Search Algo

Tags: algorithm, turbo-c++

What I know is Linear Search and Sequential Search are same, if my knowledge is correct then kindly guide me wether the below algorithm work for linear search or not as it is a Sequential Search algorithm.

1. Initialize searcharray, searchno, length.
2. Initialize pos=0.
3. Repeat step 4 till pos<=length.
4. if searcharray[pos]=searchno
      return pos
   else
       increment pos by 1.

Secondly I need help on how can I move found value at the first element of an array

Comment: Yes, linear search and sequential search mean the same thing, and if you change the word "till" to "while" (perhaps a slight language problem?) then your algorithm is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "move the found value [to] the first element of an array"?  In almost all languages, that would be written something like `searcharray[0] = searcharray[pos];`.  Do you instead want to *swap* the value in the first element with the found element?  If so, this requires a third variable to temporarily hold the contents of one element.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Your guess is 100% correct Suppose my array contain 5,6,7,2,3,4,9 and I searched for 2 then array should look like this 2,5,6,7,3,4,9

Comment: Well that is not swapping: swapping would result in 2,6,7,5,3,4,9.  Swapping is sometimes useful because it's fast; if you really need to *insert* the 2 at the front and push the others back, you need to do a lot of copying.  First you need to copy element 2 to element 3, then element 1 to element 2, then element 0 to element 1, to make room for the original value of element 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear search of a number from an array, it might be success or failed.

Your algorithm should define success or failed return. Such as position index for success and negative number for failed.

Try to think like this: Moving until you find the position.

Your number define as target. Given length and array A.

```
int linearSearch(int target, int* A, int length) {
  int pos = length - 1;
  while ( pos >= 0 and target != A[pos] ) --pos;
  return pos;
}
```

Here, If your target number is not in array, you'll get a -1 returned.

This will simple and elegant. But if you have duplicate target number, you may think how to handle them. Return one of you found or return all position.